# Smoke Sim rendering in Viewport but not in final render (2.8, Cycles)

Tags: smoke-simulation

Im trying to render a scene which contains a smoke simulation. It renders in the viewport but not in the final render (both in Cycles):

[image: Viewport render VS Final Render]

Things I've checked:

- Rendering is enabled in the outliner
- Smoke has volumetric material
- Gone through render settings (none indicate any function that would prevent the render)

To preview the final render I've set the samples to 16, but that wouldn't cause this, would it?
The trees and grass are invisible in the viewport for performance reasons.

Comment: try to increase the density to above 20 in the principled volume.

Comment: Have you baked the cache ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. save Project(if you don’t save the project the bake will not work)
2. select "Smoke Domain"
3. select "Physics menu"
4. select "Cache"
5. click on the Bake

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, please take the time to format your content properly, this saves others from having to do so on your behalf.